# Add a variable to an img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am just trying to learn html & javascript.

I am using JSON to return some values. On of the values is a a link yo an image.

http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/118/5000175411118/IDShot_90x90.jpg

However this image a too small for my use. I can download an image just by changing the same ling with 225x225

This is what I have got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title> Tesco JSONP </title>

  <script   type="text/javascript">
    var pic = "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/118/5000175411118/IDShot_90x90.jpg"
    var newpic = pic.slice(0,59);
    var bigpic = newpic + '225x225.jpg';
    document.write(bigpic);
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <img src= "bigpic" />
</body>

</html>
```

This is not downloading the image - can any one advise what I am doing wrong and possibly correct my code.

Best wishes.

James

Comment: This concept seems okay for tesco, but I would not rely on this URL transformation for other websites as it may produce `404` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace()` to replace parts of the string instead, and add an ID to the image to target it, as `document.write` should be avoided like the plague.

To make sure the element is available, add the script tag at the bottom, before `</body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Tesco JSONP</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="bigpic" src="bigpic" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pic = "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/118/5000175411118/IDShot_90x90.jpg"
            document.getElementById('bigpic').src = pic.replace('90x90', '225x225');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/up5Gc/)

Comment: I'm not your servant!

Comment: It was just a joke, "Thank you James" sounds like something you would say to your butler. I realized it was your name, but it still sounded funny!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I was concerned that I had abused your generosity in answering my question so quickly. James

Answer (score 2):

Well, a couple things to run through.

1. `document.write` rewrites your entire page with what you tell it to, this is typically not used. You should target a specific element to modify, not the entire page.
2. You want to set the source of an image, so you'll have to target that image. The easiest way to target elements is with an ID, so we'll add one for this example.

New markup:

```
<body>

   <img id="myImage" />

</body>
```

You can set a default `src` attribute if you'd like, but for time, I won't. Now, you have your image `src` attribute above, so its time to set it:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = bigpic;
```

When setting variables, you will NOT quote them! Quoting the variable will simply parse what's between the quotes. In your case, you were writing the words "bigpic" on the document, not the variable `bigpic`

Answer (score 0):

Give your img an id tag and then:

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src=bigpic;
```